# How can I add a login field to my access database

Tags: database, ms-access

I want to add 2 users. "Admin" and "User" and give Admin full privileges whilst restricting access to the "User" so that the User can only view information and not alter it.
What would be the best way of doing this?
It is an ACCDB format
Thanks, Kieran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options depend on whether your database is in MDB or ACCDB format.

With MDB format you can use ULS (user level security) to define the permissions for user groups.  And you can do that in a granular fashion for read, edit, design, etc. privileges on various db objects: tables; queries; forms; etc.

With ACCDB, ULS is not available so you need to "role your own" solution and that will not be enforced by the db engine.  But you could alter a form's properties at run time based on the current user's role: make the form read-only for "users"; and read-write for "admin".  Beware such schemes can be easily defeated by a determined user with even moderate Access experience.  For example, a "user" could open a table directly in datasheet view, bypassing the form based on that table.  So as "real security", this is especially weak.  But if your goal is to guide cooperative and trustworthy users, this may be adequate.

A stronger form of security would be to set Windows user permissions on the db file.  Give read-write permission to your admin users and read-only to the unprivileged users.

Comment: Hi, I just set securities on windows permissions. I think that would be adequate. Thanks for your help